# Change Fields of Comments and make them searchable?

Tags: custom-field

What I am trying to do is a bit complex.. but I think it can be done.

I wish to make a Wordpress website that allows anyone (not registered) to make a comment on a blog post. Only I'd like to add custom fields (Checkboxes and Text Fields)other than the default ones to the comments and display them with those fields.

If possible I'd also like to somehow make these comments "Searchable" using tags or categories.. is this possible?

Should I use Posts Instead?

Thanks, ~Sean.

Answer (score 0):

Adding additional fields to comments isn't hard. There are tons of decent tutorials out there (and probably prebuilt plugins too). Google it. Here's an example: http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2012/05/08/adding-custom-fields-in-wordpress-comment-form/

As far as I know, searching on tags + categories + comments isn't possible. I'm confused on why you'd want to search on comments?

Comment: The reason I wanted to add "tags" or "categories" to comments is I was going to try and let people filter comments based on those categories or tags.